# How can I detect if array have year value and define it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Here is example array:

```
[ 'test', '1994', 'test', 'test', '2018']
```

What I need is 2 arrays out of example array:

```
[ 'test', 'test', 'test' ]
```

and

```
[ '1994', '2018' ]
```

I tried to use `indexOf` but seams I can't pass array with all possiable years value (~1900-present/2018)

I figure out what `switch statment` will work but it's gonna be a lot of copy pasted code, I believe there is better way to do it.

Edit:

Some of you didn't understand what I wanted to get **year** value not just a **number**, so answer with regex is most closed to what I wanted, i just replace regex after googling to `^(19|20)\d{2}$`. So year could be only 1900-2099.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to do this:

```
var arr = [ 'test', '1994', 'test', 'test', '2018'];
var dates = [];
var nonDates = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].match(/^\d{4}$/))
        dates.push(arr[i]);
    else
        nonDates.push(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

You could take a check `isNaN` and push the value to either number ot text array.

```js
var array = ['test', '1994', 'test', 'test', '2018'],
    text = [],
    numbers = [];

array.forEach(s => [numbers, text][+/^(19|20)\d{2}$/.test(s)].push(s));
    
console.log(text);
console.log(numbers);
```

Comment: @Ele, which part do you mean?

Comment: it is an property accessor with a numerical value by using an unary `plus` and the boolean result of the check of `isNaN`.

Comment: Clever solution. I like it!

Comment: cleaver and short but not exactly what I wanted, read post edit.

Comment: you could take th regular expression instead of `isNaN`.

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce the array to 2 separate arrays. Check if the string can be casted to a number between the range of 1900-2018, and if it evaluates to:

1. `false` - casted to 0, and pushed to the 1st sub-array
2. `true` - casted to 1, and pushed to the 2nd sub-array

Then you can get the two arrays using array destructuring.

```js
const arr = ['test', '1994', 'test', 'test', '2018'];

const isYear = (n) => n >= 1900 && n <= 2018;

const [test, years] = arr.reduce((r, s) => {
  r[+isYear(+s)].push(s);
  
  return r;
}, [[], []]);

console.log(test);

console.log(years);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `reduce` to group the strings according to their contents.

```js
let arr = [ 'test', '1994', 'test', 'test', '2018'],
    isYear = (s) => !isNaN(Number(s.trim())),
    result = arr.reduce((a, s) => {
      if (isYear(s)) a.years.push(s);
      else a.strings.push(s);
      return a;
    } , {years: [], strings: []});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) along with the [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) check to accomplish this.

```js
var array = ['test', '1994', 'test', 'test', '2018'];

var text = array.filter(e => isNaN(e)),
    years = array.filter(e => !isNaN(e));
    
console.log(text);
console.log(years);
```